# Woocommerce Variable Products Create Variations From all Attributes

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce

I have 9 colors and 5 sizes such as (S,M,L,XL,XXL) S-XL having same prices, I need to add extra price for XXL. If I tick used for variations its showing 45 products. Why? and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In woocommerce we can not give price for attribute value. It will take all the variations like 9x5=45 variations.